# How to use a pandas data frame in a unit test

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest

I am developing a set of python scripts to pre-process a dataset then produce a series of machine learning models using scikit-learn. I would like to develop a set of unittests to check the data pre-processing functions, and would like to be able to use a small test pandas dataframe for which I can determine the answers for and use it in assert statements.

I cannot seem to get it to load the dataframe and to pass it to the unit tests using self. My code looks something like this;

```
def setUp(self):
    TEST_INPUT_DIR = 'data/'
    test_file_name =  'testdata.csv'
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(INPUT_DIR + test_file_name,
            sep = ',',
            header = 0)
    except IOError:
        print 'cannot open file'
    self.fixture = data

def tearDown(self):
    del self.fixture

def test1(self):    
    self.assertEqual(somefunction(self.fixture), somevalue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean "you cannot get it to"?  Is there an error?  If so, what is the error?  What do you want to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I do not get an error, the test runs successfully whatever I put in the test. What I want to be able to do is produce tests which test functions that manipulate a pandas dataframe and confirm their behaviour using a small test dataframe.

Comment: You'll need to show an actual example with actual data that isn't working.

Comment: When you are using `self`, you have to put these functions inside a class.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried to get an example to work with an embedded data frame but with no luck. I will tomorrow try building the class to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pandas has some utilities for testing.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal # <-- for testing dataframes

class DFTests(unittest.TestCase):

    """ class for running unittests """

    def setUp(self):
        """ Your setUp """
        TEST_INPUT_DIR = 'data/'
        test_file_name =  'testdata.csv'
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(INPUT_DIR + test_file_name,
                sep = ',',
                header = 0)
        except IOError:
            print 'cannot open file'
        self.fixture = data

    def test_dataFrame_constructedAsExpected(self):
        """ Test that the dataframe read in equals what you expect"""
        foo = pd.DataFrame()
        assert_frame_equal(self.fixture, foo)
```

Comment: Import from `pandas.testing` in the latest pandas - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Answer (score 34):

If you are using latest pandas, I think the following way is a bit cleaner:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(my_df, expected_df)
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(my_series, expected_series)
pd.testing.assert_index_equal(my_index, expected_index)
```

Each of these functions will raise `AssertionError` if they are not "equal".

For more information and options: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/testing.html

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this as well with `snapshottest`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070787/3384609