# How do you Unit Test Python DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, unit-testing

How do I unit test Python dataframes?

I have functions that have an input and output as dataframes. Almost every function I have does this. Now if I want to unit test this what is the best method of doing it? It seems a bit of an effort to create a new dataframe (with values populated) for every function?

Are there any materials you can refer me to? Should you write unit tests for these functions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

While Pandas' test functions are primarily used for internal testing, NumPy includes a very useful set of testing functions that are documented here: [NumPy Test Support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.testing.html).

These functions compare NumPy arrays, but you can get the array that underlies a Pandas DataFrame using the `values` property. You can define a simple DataFrame and compare what your function returns to what you expect.

One technique you can use is to define one set of test data for a number of functions. That way, you can use [Pytest Fixtures](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html) to define that DataFrame once, and use it in multiple tests.

In terms of resources, I found this article on [Testing with NumPy and Pandas](https://penandpants.com/2014/10/07/testing-with-numpy-and-pandas/) to be very useful. I also did a short presentation about data analysis testing at PyCon Canada 2016: [Automate Your Data Analysis Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovvU41ve1FQ).

Comment: Just a quick update, the Pytest Fixtures link is broken. Maybe they moved the page. Here's their ["About Fixtures"](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html) page!

Comment: PyData London 2019, excellent vid on the topic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTj6T0QdHHM&t=4432s

Answer (score 35):

you can use pandas testing functions:

It will give more flexbile to compare your result with computed result in different ways.

For example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[6,7,8,9,10]})

expected_res=pd.Series([7,9,11,13,15])
pd.testing.assert_series_equal((df1['a']+df2['a']),expected_res,check_names=False)
```

For more details refer this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/api.html#testing-functions)

Comment: My approach thanks to this answer: `assert_frame_equal(mock_obj.call_args.args[0]['first_dict_key_which_points_to_a_df'], expected_df)`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using pytest, `pandasSnapshot` will be useful.

```
# use with pytest
import pandas as pd
from snapshottest_ext.dataframe import PandasSnapshot

def test_format(snapshot):
    df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                      columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
    snapshot.assert_match(PandasSnapshot(df))
```

One big cons is that the snapshot is not readable anymore. (store the content as csv is more readable, but it is problematic.

PS: I am the author of pytest snapshot extension.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's hard to create small DataFrames for unit testing?

```
import pandas as pd
from nose.tools import assert_dict_equal

input_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'field_1': [some, values],
    'field_2': [other, values]
})
expected = {
    'result': [...]
}
assert_dict_equal(expected, my_func(input_df).to_dict(), "oops, there's a bug...")
```

Comment: My result is a dataframe too. So i should create another dataframe? in this case i cant use assert_dict_equal?

Comment: Yes, that's why I called `to_dict()` on the result from your function - so I get a `dict` that can be compared to `expected` with the `nose` method suggested.

Comment: @rkaleta : yes it does.. However, my test fail with errors like AssertionError: {'ins[20 chars]on': ['TF000141124', 'TF000141124', 'TF00014[599 chars]0.0]} != {'ins[20 chars]on': {0: 'TF000141124', 1: 'TF000141124', 2:[716 chars]0.0}}
Diff is 3078 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it. : oops, there's a bug...

Comment: @CodeGeek123 The above code for `expected` was just an example - you have to modify to your needs. Looks like you have a mismatch in the _expected_ vs. _actual_ DataFrame structure. It looks like the function under test returns a DataFrame that is 3 rows x 1 column? Then _expected_ should be more like `expected = {<column_name>: {<first_row_index_value>: <first_row_value>, <second_row_index_value>: <second_row_value>, <third_row_index_value: <third_row_value>}}`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `snapshottest` and do something like this:

```py
def test_something_works(snapshot): # snapshot is a pytest fixture from snapshottest
    data_frame = calc_something_and_return_pandas_dataframe()
    snapshot.assert_match(data_frame.to_csv(index=False), 'some_module_level_unique_name_for_the_snapshot')
```

This will create a snapshots folder with a file in that contains the csv output that you can update with `--snapshot-update` when your code changes.

It works by comparing the `data_frame` variable to what is saved to disk.

Might be worth mentioning that your snapshots should be checked in to source control.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest writing the values as CSV in docstrings (or separate files if they're large) and parsing them using `pd.read_csv()`.  You can parse the expected output from CSV too, and compare, or else use `df.to_csv()` to write a CSV out and diff it.

Comment: This is a nice idea but dealing with `csv` files can be annoying if your DataFrame has data in strange encodings, or arrays that you need to `literal_eval`, etc. If her code is structured correctly the input/expected DataFrames should be fairly small and therefore easy to construct on the fly?

Answer (score 3):

Pandas has built in testing functions, but I don't find the output easy to parse, so I created an open source project called [beavis](https://github.com/MrPowers/beavis) with functions that output error messages that are easier for humans to read.

Here's an example of one of the built in testing methods:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1042, 2, 9, 6], "col2": [5, 2, 7, 6]})
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(df["col1"], df["col2"])
```

Here's the error message:

```
>   ???
E   AssertionError: Series are different
E
E   Series values are different (50.0 %)
E   [index]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
E   [left]:  [1042, 2, 9, 6]
E   [right]: [5, 2, 7, 6]
```

Not very easy to see which rows are mismatched because the output isn't aligned.

Here's how you can write the same test with beavis.

```py
import beavis

beavis.assert_pd_column_equality(df, "col1", "col2")
```

This'll give you the following readable error message:

[image: Columns not equal error]

The built-in `assert_frame_equal` doesn't give a readable error message either.  Here's how you can compare DataFrame equality with beavis.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
beavis.assert_pd_equality(df1, df2)
```

[image: Beavis DataFrame equality]

Answer (score 1):

The [frame-fixtures](https://github.com/InvestmentSystems/frame-fixtures) Python package (of which I am an author) is designed to make it easy to "create a new dataframe (with values populated)" for unit or performance tests.

For example, if you want to test against a DataFrame of floats and strings with a numerical index, you can use a compact string declaration to generate a DataFrame.

```py
>>> ff.Fixture.to_frame('i(I,int)|v(float,str)|s(4,2)').to_pandas()
              0     1
 34715  1930.40  zaji
-3648  -1760.34  zJnC
 91301  1857.34  zDdR
 30205  1699.34  zuVU

>>> ff.Fixture.to_frame('i(I,int)|v(float,str)|s(8,3)').to_pandas()
               0     1        2
 34715   1930.40  zaji   694.30
-3648   -1760.34  zJnC   -72.96
 91301   1857.34  zDdR  1826.02
 30205   1699.34  zuVU   604.10
 54020    268.96  zKka  1080.40
 129017  3511.58  zJXD  2580.34
 35021   1175.36  zPAQ   700.42
 166924  2925.68  zyps  3338.48
```