# How to test if saved csv file is correct

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, mocking

I have a small function which returns nothing but creates csv file instead.
I would like to unittest it if given output csv file contains proper data.
How can I achieve that?

function

```
def create_csv(input, output)
    df = pd.read_csv(input, names=['number1', 'number2'])
    df.number1 *= 2
    df.number2 *= 5
    df.to_csv(output, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Print it before saving

Comment: I do not want to print it

Comment: What are you passing to the `input` and `output` parameters?

Comment: paths of the input and output file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.to_csv` and `.read_csv` take buffers as well as string paths. [The docs for those methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-tools-text-csv-hdf5) suggest using io.StringIO as an alternative to an open file or file path.

In the unit test,  use [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) objects to pass to the function during the test.  Something like this for a simple test of the function

```
import unittest, io
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        s = '''3,4\n2,1\n5,6'''
        self.fakecsv = io.StringIO(s)
        self.fakefile = io.StringIO()
        self.result = '''6,20\n4,5\n10,30\n'''

    def test_create(self):
        create_csv(self.fakecsv, self.fakefile)
        self.fakefile.seek(0)
        self.assertEqual(self.fakefile.read(), self.result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Test the data frame just before you persist it to a CSV file. The [NumPy test scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852686/how-do-you-unit-test-python-dataframes) and [Pandas test functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#testing-functions) can be helpful. If you feel you need to test the CSV file itself, you are actually distrusting pandas' `to_csv()` function. The best course of action then is to [review the unit tests of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/wiki/Testing), and if you feel it is lacking do a pull request to amend it with the tests you feel are missing.